# How to modify column values within a SELECT statement

Tags: sql

I have a column named "Sub channel" which contains values like:

```
gujrat channel,Delhi_channel,ROMG channel etc.
```

I want to format the values for a report. So the values should look like this instead:

```
Gujrat,Delhi,ROMG .
```

Basically I want to remove the word "channel" from the values.  How can I do that?

Comment: More details, please. And consider formatting your code. The question is unreadable at the moment.

Comment: Modified to improve formatting.

Answer (score 1):

What flavor SQL -  In TSQL I would use `REPLACE` and  get rid of both channel and _channel.
Syntax and link for `REPLACE`:

[REPLACE (string_expression,string_pattern,string_replacement)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE([Sub channel],'_channel',''),'channel','') FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
update table as tab1 
inner join 
(Select id, REPLACE('_channel','') as new_column from table) tab2 on (tab1.id=tab2.id)
set tab1.column = tab2.new_column
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up the string functions in your vender's documentation, and use the appropriate one.

If you're using postgresql, then go [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) and pick a function that meets your needs. You might use "replace" or "regex_replace".

Here's an example using replace:

```
SELECT replace(t1.col1, 'channel', '') AS col1 FROM t1;
```

That selects all of the rows from a table named "t1", and selects the "col1" column, and strips the word channel from, and names the column "col1" (by default it would be named "replace" in postgres).